# How to find any point inside of a triangle knowing all three points?

Tags: 3d, geometry, coordinates

Say I have a triangle in three dimensions, and I know the coordinates (x,y,z) of every point - how would I go about finding any point that lies inside of this triangle? Say I know the x and y of the point I want, how would I find the Z?

EDIT: alfasin's answers was closest to the solution - I used the three points to construct a plane equation

a(x-x0) + b(y-y0) + c(z-z0) = 0

where (a,b,c) is the normal vector and plugged in my values and solved for Z. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: For what application do you need this? You can project the Point to a plane (see [How to project a 3d point to a 3d plane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605556/how-to-project-a-3d-point-to-a-3d-plane)) and check if the projected point is inside the triangle. This can be done using barycentric coordinates (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6075960/2344898)).

Comment: I have a triangle in 3D space and I want to be able to pick (x,y,z) where I am positive the x and y coordinates exist inside of this triangle. I then need to know, however, what the Z coordinate is at this Point.

Comment: You can only be certain that the point is 'inside' the triangle if you have some kind of projection. What you need is a Ray-Triangle intersection test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the equation that represents the surface by applying the 3 points to the following:

```
ax+by+cz+d = 0
```

after you found a,b and c you have the surface - so the first thing would be to check if point P is on the surface. If it is, we still have to check that it's on the triangle.

For that we'll create a diagonal line, that goes through P, to each one of the edges, or to be more exact, to the linear equation which "includes" the edges (please excuse my poor English - I learned this stuff in my native language so bear with me).

This can be done by taking *each pair* of points (from the triangle), say `A=(x1,y1,z1)` and `B=(x2,y2,z2)` and assigning them to the first equation. we'll get a linear equation:

`y = mx + n`.

Here `m` is the `incline` - so the diagonal equation will have

```
m' = -1/m
```

and since we know the values of `P` we can use both to find the value of `n`.
Now that we have both equations we can find the point that exists on both lines. Let's call this point P'.

It's easy to find if P' is between `A` and `B`. if it is (for every pair!) - then P is inside the triangle, else, it's not.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your triangle is made of three points T1, T2, T3 and the point you're trying to find is P, you could do a cross product between lines:

(T1, T2) x (T1, P) = R1

(T2, T3) x (T2, P) = R2

(T3, T1) x (T3, P) = R3

If the resultant lines R1, R2, R3 are parallel, then I would assume the point is within the triangle. Could someone verify/disprove this?

[Edit]: Here's a resource to find if lines are parallel: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194242/decide-whether-two-lines-are-parallel

But the second part of your question implies that you're trying to MAKE a point fit into a triangle? Is this correct? Excuse the lack of commenting- I don't have the SO cred to do so at the moment.

Comment: I'm saying that I'm picking a point (x,y,z) where I am CERTAIN the x and y coordinates are inside of this particular triangle, but I need to find the Z coordinate.

Comment: Alright. That changes that up a bit. Thanks for clarifying. You COULD do the method described above and try to approximate by seeing how close to 1, or -1 the parallel lines will get (using the parallelism method described in the link I added to my initial comment). Otherwise, let me look some more...